# if i have no right use the flag "Accepted",please hide it

Tags: flags

when user have no permission use flag "Accepted",how to hide it instead of when clicking and tell them "you have no permission"?

I found a function on flag.module: function template_preprocess_flag(&$variables) ,

but it seems not a hook to reuse...

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this to my sites/all/themes/mytheme/template.php file and it worked after clearing the theme registry:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_flag(&$variables) {
  // Do something here
  dpm($variables);  // Pretty print $variables if you have the Devel module installed
}
```

That should give you a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: you're right,I have done that... both in module level and theme level...

Comment: but I have much php warning logs in drupal....

Comment: MESSAGE Notice: Undefined variable: flag_wrapper_classes in include() (line 33 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/druedu/trunk/sites/all/modules/flag/theme/flag.tpl.php).

Comment: In my flag.tpl.php ,I should have a if(isset($flag) && !is_null($flag)){//then do the tpl....

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * If I have no right use it, please hide it. 
 * @see druedu_preprocess_flag in theme level.
 */

 function crystal_qa_preprocess_flag(&$variables) {  
  $flag = flag_load('accepted');  

  if (!$flag->access($variables['content_id'])) {
    $variables = NULL;
  }
}
```

We needed to override the flag.tpl.php file to avoid errors in the log:

```
if (isset($flag) && !is_null($flag)) {
  // Render.
}
```

Comment: must be null,not array() or unset()